# Which block does block.number point to?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Does `block.number` point to the last mined block or the one current transaction is going to be mined within?

It's not quite clear from reading 
https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the current block number (the one the transaction is a part of):

> block.number (uint): current block number

Comment: How is that possible if the block contains the `stateRoot` after all the ytansactions are executed?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The block number is just how many blocks there have been. Each block's number is one greater than the previous block's.

Comment: Yeah, but this suggests that `block.coinbase`, `block.timestamp` and `block.blockhash(block.number)` also return the data for the block the transaction is a part of, I don't understand how is that possible if that block doesn't exist yet when the transaction is processed (and if it does, how can the `stateRoot` be known beforehand?)

Comment: The current block hash is unavailable (for the reason you stated), so `block.blockhash(block.number)` returns 0. `block.coinbase` and `block.timestamp` work fine and refer to the current block.

Comment: which one is the current block? the same as `block.number`? (because they're inside that same block)

Comment: Yes, `block.number` is the number of the block this transaction is a part of. `block.timestamp` is the timestamp for that same block, etc.

Comment: But the miner is the one to set that. how then can full nodes verify the transactions? only after receiving them in a block?
It makes no sense to process them only after they're in a block

Comment: Again, I'm not sure what you're asking. Miners don't add invalid transactions to a block, because after the block is mined, it will be rejected by other nodes if it's invalid.

Comment: By verify I mean execute. And the only reason miners don't add invalid transactions is because full nodes will reject these blocks

Comment: Yes, other nodes verify all transactions in a block (by executing them) after they receive that block. Does that answer your question?

Comment: yes. Thanks. I just found no record of this online. if they execute and verify on receiving an unconfirmed transaction or only when receiving them in a block.

Comment: Miners execute the code as part of building the block. Everyone executes the code when they receive a new block.